# Blazor Web App with public pages and private pages

Tags: blazor, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I am trying to create a website with Blazor Web Apps that contains both publicly accessible pages and pages that require the user to be logged in (OpenID) to view them. What is the cleanest way to implement this.

One approach is to work with multiple layouts, where I have a LoggedIn layout and a LoggedOut layout.

The LoggedIn Layout

```
/// <summary>
/// LoggedIn Layout
/// </summary>
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync() {

   // Load user
   if (authenticationState is not null) {

       //Check authentication state and store user
       var authState = await authenticationState;
       var user = authState?.User;

       //Check if user is authenticated
       if (user is not null) {
           if (user.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {

               //Initialise current user service
               this.CurrentUserService.Initialize(user.Claims);

               //Return
               return;
           }
       }
   }

   //Redirect user to login page
   var challengeUri = "/login?redirectUri=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(NavigationManager.Uri);
   NavigationManager.NavigateTo(challengeUri, true);

 }
```

The LoggedOut Layout

```
/// <summary>
/// LoggedOut Layout
/// </summary>
private async Task LoadUser() {

// Load user
if (authenticationState is not null) {

    //Check authentication state and store user
    var authState = await authenticationState;
    var user = authState?.User;

    //Check if user is authenticated
    if (user is not null) {
        if (user.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {

            //Initialise current user service
            this.CurrentUserService.Initialize(user.Claims);

        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem with this approach is that when I switch from a LoggedOut page to a LoggedIn page, the page is rendered first, then the new layout is rendered and then the page is rendered again, which triggers an error in the asynchronous database query in the OnInitializedAsync function.

```
Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.
```

Another way is to work with  attributes as described [here in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0), but the documentation does not explain how I can make multiple pages publicly accessible.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add two folders (or folder structures) Public and Private.  Add an `_Imports.razor` to Private and add the security attribute

```cs
@attribute [Authorize]
```

This will now be applied to all pages in `Private` and any sub folders.  They will need an authenticated user.